# Is heat dissipation/heat loss a part of this Heat Generation formula?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, dissipation

I have been using a formula to calculate how much heat needs to be generated by a pipe in order to raise the temperature of the water flowing through the pipe by a certain amount, e.g. from $10^o$ C to $30^o$ C.
The formula is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7D8n-lLIV24).

In this video, the speaker says “this pipe is heated by uniform heat generation”. She also says that the pipe “ is insulated, which means all the heat is going to go to heating the water within the pipe”.
I want to know if this formula accounts for the Heat Dissipation through the convection in the water going through the pipe. I am thinking that it does not, since the speaker says the heat in the pipe is uniform. Am I correct in thinking this?

The formula is  Heat generation in Watts per cubic meter = Heat Transfer rate in Watts divided by Volume in Cubic meters

$$Q_{transfer}=mc_p(T_{out} - T_{in})$$
Where

$m$ = flow rate in kg/s

$c_p $=Heat capacity of water in J/Kg-K

$T_{out}$ = desired temperature in C

$T_{in}$ = starting temperature in C

$$V = \frac{\pi}{4}(d_{out}^2 - d_{in}^2)l $$
where $d$ stands for diammeter and $l$ for the lenght of pipe.
All in meters

The speaker says “the reason we look at the volume of the pipe wall is that that is where the heat is being generated”. If the temperature of the pipe is uniform in this situation, is it assumed that the pipe receives a constant supply of energy that keeps the pipe temperature from changing? Am I right in thinking that we do not need to calculate the heat loss in the pipe as the heat is dissipated in the water because the energy supply to the pipe, and therefore the heat in the pipe, is assumed to be constant?

Comment: Uniform temperature means it does not change.

Comment: Normally, heat is generated by something on the outside of a pipe, not by the pipe itself.  Also, MOST heat goes into heating the water in the pipe and some heat is lost to the environment through the pipe insulation.  I'm not sure what you mean by "I want to know if this formula accounts for the Heat Dissipation through the convection in the water going through the pipe".  There is no "heat dissipation" via convection ... the water absorbs heat from the pipe wall.  What does "the temperature in the pipe is uniform" mean?

Comment: More comments: The temperature increases down the pipe in the direction of water flow, and so does the water temperature.  At steady state, for a particular spot on the pipe, the temperature does not change.  Please consider editing your questions to increase clarity.  Also consider adding information to tell the forum what you are trying to do regarding your water heating application.

Comment: Your formula assumes that the heat is generated within the water rather within the pipe wall.

Comment: @ChetMiller, if you watch the YouTube video (link provided by the OP), you'll be "amazed".

Comment: @David White Well, I guess that will give the mixing cup average temperature of the water coming out, but it won’t be uniform.  Did you estimate the Re for the flow and the Fourier number based on the average velocity?

Comment: @ChetMiller, hopefully you're being facetious.  My observation of the calculations: a flow rate in kg/s was specified, the proper heat transfer calculation for the "water side" of the pipe was specified, then a calculation of $W/m^3$ was shown.  The $W/m^3$ calculation is totally irrelevant, and it should be $J/m^3$ if it is included at all.

Comment: @Daviid White I don't see what you are saying.  What she is trying to calculate is the average heating rate within the pipe wall, which is somehow being heated uniformly. So she divided the overall heating rate (W) by the volume of the pipe (m^3).  Maybe what she did is not as bad as what I thought.  Based on a viscosity of 0.01 Poise for the water (upper limit over the temperature range), I get a minimum Reynolds number of 45000.  So the flow is turbulent, and the radial temperature variation will be much less than if the flow were laminar.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. @David White I want to use this formula to calculate heat generation in another object, different from a pipe. If I have a disk containing many holes, I want to calculate the heat in the disk necessary in order to heat the water flowing through the holes. I want to put the volume of the disk into the Volume section of the formula. I thought the presence of other holes would make this invalid, but if the disk does not lose heat through the holes, I feel like inputting the disk volume would let me calculate the heat needed. Am I right in thinking this?

Comment: @EddieP, the formula to calculate the heat rise in the water is definitely correct.  My confusion with your stated problem is the heat source.  If the pipe in the problem statement or the disk that you want to use are not radioactive, where is the heat coming from?  THAT heat source must be able to provide the heat going into the water and small heat losses to the environment.  And if the pipe or your disk is not radioactive (a good assumption), there is no heat generation in the volume of the metal ... the metal just conducts heat provided by the heat source.